# Trying to understand this variable definition

Tags: c++

What exactly does this do?

```
int test = *(int*)(0x154512);
```

Comment: 0x154512 is a memory address that will stored into a temporary pointer to an int type then it value will dereference and copied into test variable

Comment: So this reads the memory at 0x154512? Or does it read where 0x154512 is pointing at?

Comment: @IInspectable: well, it is also a declaration, just like every definition is :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Well, yes, that was a bit sloppy, on my end. Still, though, a declaration doesn't *do* anything, so I felt the distinction was relevant.

Answer (score 7):

```
0x154512
```

is an integer, written in base 16.

```
(int*)(0x154512)
```

says to treat that number as the address of an `int` variable.

```
*(int*)(0x154512)
```

says to dereference that address, or get the `int` value at that address.

```
int test = *(int*)(0x154512)
```

says to declare the `int` variable `test` and assign it the `int` value located at address 0x154512.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break this down into pieces.

`0x154512` is a hex value, or base-16, which is often used for memory addresses for convenience reasons.

`int*` declares a pointer to a value of type int. So, `(int*)(0x154512)` means 0x154512 is being treated as a memory address, which we expect to hold an integer.

The last `*` on the left is the *dereference operator*, which means "get the value located at this pointer" more or less.

So it copies the integer at memory address 0x154512 to the variable "test".

For more information on pointers:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

If you're planning to do a lot of C++ in the future, make sure to give this a nice, long read. Pointers are fun.

Answer (score 0):

One line get integer value stored at 0x154512 memory location